# Google Maps API geocode function problem

Tags: google-maps-api-3, javascript

Ok, I'm fooling around with [Google Maps API v3](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/index.html) and I bumped into a problem. I don't know if its the API or just some JS error i made.

Problem:
`addMarkerFromAdress()` function calls on `geocodeFromAdress()` which returns coordinates back to `addMarkerFromAdress()`. But returned value is "***undefined***".

As a debug i added two alert outputs, one in `addMarkerFromAdress()` and one in `geocodeFromAdress()`. What troubles me is that the `alert()` in `addMarkerFromAdress()` seems to fire off before any value is returned. Why?

**Source:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var geocoder;
  var map;

  function initializeGoogleMaps() {

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 1,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  }

  function geocodeFromAdress(address) {
   geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
        alert(latLng); //Outputs coordinates, but is for some reason outputted 2nd
        return latLng;
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }

  function addMarkerFromAdress(address, title){

    var latLng = geocodeFromAdress(address); 
    alert(latLng); //Outputs "undefined", but is for some reason outputted 1st
    map.setCenter(latLng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map, 
            position: latLng
    });

  }

  window.onload = function () { 
   initializeGoogleMaps();
   addMarkerFromAdress('Berlin, Germany', 'Berlin');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See that function passed as the second argument to `geocoder.geocode()`? that is where you should be calling `addMarkerFromAddress`. Due to the asynchronous nature of the geocode request, the `alert` after `var latLng = geocodeFromAdress(address);` is firing before the response is returned with the lat long values.

Something like this should do it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var geocoder;
  var map;

  function initializeGoogleMaps() {

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 1,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  }

  function geocodeFromAdress(address, title) {
   geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
        addMarkerFromAdress(latLng, title);
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }

  function addMarkerFromAdress(latLng, title){
    map.setCenter(latLng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map, 
        position: latLng
    });   
  }

  window.onload = function () { 
   initializeGoogleMaps();
   geocodeFromAdress('Berlin, Germany', 'Berlin');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: So I cannot just get the coordinates from geocoder? I must actually use them in the same function.

Comment: Not in the way that you have coded it. You can get the coordinates from the geocoder, but you don't know when they are going to be returned, so you need to write your code such that when they are returned, they are passed to `addMarkerFromAdress` function to place a point on the map.

Comment: Then I might as well have all code inside `geocodeFromAdress()` ? I still cant gasp is why `addMarkerFromAdress()` continues before the `geocodeFromAdress()` returns a value. Sure, I understand what your saying, and it seems right, but i still don't understand it :P

Comment: The request is an AJAX request. You don't know when it will be returned, but when it does return, you know what the status is, whether it is ok or gone wrong in some way. That's what the status is for. You could write the code in many different ways but essentially it doesn't work the way that you have originally written it i.e. `geoCodeFromAdress` will **not** block until the response is returned from the geocode request. You could change `geoCodeFromAdress` to take a function that is called when the response is returned.

Comment: It's the difference between a synchronous and asynchronous operation. You can make an AJAX request with async set to false but I wouldn't recommend this on the whole as the whole UI will be blocked until the response is returned, potentially giving the user a jerky experience. You might want to keep the functions separate if you were to know lat long values without needing to call `geocodeFromAdress`, you can simply pass these to `addMarkerFromAdress` :)