# Javascript jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-geocoder

I am trying to follow this [Google Maps API geocode function problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172710/google-maps-api-geocode-function-problem) code to use the Google Geocode API, but I'm doing something wrong. I am starting with the geocode and then the jQuery validator but somehow the status is not getting set. Any help?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var shvalidator = $('#post').validate({
    rules: {
      post_title: { required:true }
    },
    messages:  { 
        post_title: {required:jQuery.format("Enter the name of the venue")} 
    }
  });

  function getAddress() {

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var fulladdress = $('#sh_venue_address1').val()+' ' \
      +$('#sh_venue_address2').val()+' ' \
      +$('#sh_venue_city').val()+' ' \
      +$('#sh_venue_state').val()+' ' \
      +$('#sh_venue_postalcode').val();

    alert(fulladdress );
    var a,b;

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': fulladdress},
    function(results, status) {
     //**// 
     if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        a = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        b = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        setAddress(a,b);
      }
    });
  }

  // this is the callback method that waits for response from google
  function setAddress(lat,lng) {
    $('#sh_venue_latitude').val(lat);
    $('#sh_venue_longitude').val(lng);
    alert ($('#sh_venue_latitude').val());
  }

  // this is used to validate the form before submitting
  $('#post').submit(function() {
    getAddress();
    if (shvalidator.valid()==true){
      return true;
    } else {
      $('#ajax-loading').hide();
      $('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: do console.log(arguments), what do you get?

Comment: I get undefined for status

Comment: the code runs fine till //**// but then it skips over setting of variables a and b because the status is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is not working because the function getAddress is not executed completely before the processing of the submit (because its an asynchronous call for geocoding the address).
I would suppose to do sth like this in the submit function:

```
getAddress(function(){
if (shvalidator.valid()==true){
      return true;
    } else {
      $('#ajax-loading').hide();
      $('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');
      return false;
    }
});
```

and change the getAddress function to:

```
function getAddress(callback){
...
setAddress(a,b);
callback();

...
}
```